# get changed context value after component re renders inside helper function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Intention:
I have a component called "ABC", and I am calling a helper function in a different file called "initTimer". Inside "initTimer" function I intend to change the context value using "setResendExpTime" function, and get the changed state value accessible from "authState".

Problem:
I am able to change the context value using "setResendExpTime", ABC component does rerender but my intention was to get a new state value inside "initTimer", after setting the context value failed. I keep on getting old context values. Is there any way I can pass the changed context value?

note: Inside the helper function, I am not able to use useContext hook so I am passing it as params.

I have this code inside my component:

```
file: ABC.js component: 

const ABC = () => {
  const { authState, setResendExpTime } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const onNextPress = async () => {
      initTimer(authState, setResendExpTime);
  }

  // "setResendExpTime" called from inside of initTimer rerenders this component, and we have a new "authState" value here but not inside "initTimer"... maybe coz initTimer has already been called with the previous state value. 
}
```

```
file: helper.js

export const initTimer = (authState, setResendExpTime) => {
 
  console.log("auth val is", authState); 
  // when initTImer is called authState is {name: "", lname: ""}

  setResendExpTime({
    name: "hello",
    lname: "world"
  });

  // problem: now I want to access the changed "authState" inside this function and carry out the rest of the function call. I also wish to run setResendExpTime again and again and get changed "authState".
```

Comment: Can you not directly use `{
    name: "hello",
    lname: "world"
  }`. The state will be set in async manner and in the same function call you will not get the updated state value. Since you are the one setting it why not use it?.